# is there answer to (") these inverted commas in my navbar section without being given by me in html and css?

Tags: html, css

when i realized through Firefox inspector showing overflow in body element," is present in the page.I removed it(from inspector) but problem remains after refreshing the page.I  tried using min-max h,w,still no changes.I am not able to catch the keyword i need solution.
code:

```css
#navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    margin-top: -18px;
}

#navbar::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 1;

}

/* Nav Bar:Logo And Image  */
#logo {
    margin: 11px 30px;
}
```

```
<nav id="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="logo1.png" alt="w8.com" id="img1">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Top Searches</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Places</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

This is the portion where it is showing **inverted commas** in the top left corner.
**>**And this is the code from the inspector:

```html
<body>"
    <!-- <style>
        #img1{
            height: 66px;
            margin: 8px 12px;
            border-radius: 36px;  
        }
    </style> -->



    <nav id="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="logo1.png" alt="w8.com" id="img1">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Top Searches</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Places</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

i tried removing and rewriting the code but it didn't help.And about overflow i am not able do fix overflow.

Comment: Please add some html to your snippet so that it shows your problem.

Comment: There is nothing in the code given so far that would put an extra double quote into the page. Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and ensure you provide code which shows the problem. Thanks

Comment: Do you know any other reason for double quote into the page?

Comment: @LeeTaylor please check again.

Comment: `<body>"`......

Comment: Yes you are right,the Html code you looked into is from FireFox inspector.I never put " in my code in the code editor. I want to find what could be the reason for (") into the page.Thanks